# Changing display property dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the style:display property (none or block) of my div (displaydiv) according to the value of a global variable (disp). I want to check the value of this variable on page load and set the styel: display according to the value disp.

i set the value of disp as "none" in javascript.

i want to change the value within HTML TAG

But this div is always visible.
Please help me

Comment: Note: please accept the answer that helped you out (if at all). It provides credit to the one who gave the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function hidemydiv() {
 if(disp == 'none') document.getElementById('displaydiv').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<body onload="hidemydiv()">
<div id="displaydiv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sith amet
</div>
</body>
```

I just wonder what kind of global variable disp is. Is it in javascript? PHP? Where/when/how do you set it?

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell without code but it sounds very much like you're executing your change-style JS inline before the target DIV has loaded.

Does your browser report errors on the page?

Is your JS code bound to the onload event somehow?

Is the style actually applied but overidden (check with firebug)?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a function to the window onload event.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById(divId);

    if (disp === "none") {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        elem.style.display = "block";
    }
};
```